# Failed to fetch linux-headers-hwe

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade, updates

I don't understand why I can't `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

I get this error:

```
Get:198 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 libreoffice-pdfimport all 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.6 [6,344 B]                                                                          
Ign:185 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 linux-hwe-5.15-headers-5.15.0-58 all 5.15.0-58.64~20.04.1                                                                             
Ign:185 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 linux-hwe-5.15-headers-5.15.0-58 all 5.15.0-58.64~20.04.1
Err:185 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 linux-hwe-5.15-headers-5.15.0-58 all 5.15.0-58.64~20.04.1
  Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Fetched 509 MB in 7min 21s (1,155 kB/s)
W: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libudev1_245.4-4ubuntu3.19_amd64.deb: Automatically disabled Acquire::http::Pipeline-Depth due to incorrect response from server/proxy. (man 5 apt.conf)
W: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/perl/perl_5.30.0-9ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb: Automatically disabled Acquire::http::Pipeline-Depth due to incorrect response from server/proxy. (man 5 apt.conf)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-hwe-5.15/linux-hwe-5.15-headers-5.15.0-58_5.15.0-58.64~20.04.1_all.deb  Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
```

I can't find any solutions for this. I have tried reinstalling Ubuntu 20.04LTS twice (it's a VM). I tried apt clean, I changed the sources.list...

Here my sources.list in /etc/apt:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main universe multiverse restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main multiverse universe restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main multiverse universe restricted
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You have some network problems.

Comment: I can ping www.google.com, what's the problem ?

Comment: The connections is unstable. You can download other packages as you can see, but then connection fails.

Comment: Check the wireless troubleshooting guide.  Get signal strengths with sudo iwlist scan and see if you have noisy neighbors on your channel -- maybe reposition nearer to your router (temporarily) for the big download.

Comment: Hi DNS, Actually try changing Your "DNS".  
then `ping archive.ubuntu.com`  and `sudo apt-get update`.    
  
My `ping archive.ubuntu.com` currently returns IP 185.125.190.36.  
Your apt-get expects archive.ubuntu.com at IP: 185.125.190.39, which is currently offline.  
i.e ping 185.125.190.39 fails.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I tried using connection sharing with my phone and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a network connection problem.

To very this, run this in another window:

```
ping archive.ubuntu.com
```

Use a stable internet connection and it will work.